# How to get around TPTP's IWAT0435E in Windows

Tags: eclipse-tptp

I have just installed TPTP's latest version (4.6.1) and am using Eclipse build `20090621-0832` on Windows 7 (User Control enabled).
I'm trying to profile an application but am getting the following error under the Monitor tab:

```
IWAT0435E An error occurred when connecting to the host.
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Just completed my answer with Windows consideration related to this error message.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, this may be related to a missing reference to the [**Integrated Agent Controller (IAC)**](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.tptp.platform.agentcontroller.doc.user/concepts/ac/ciacintro.html)

> The Integrated Agent Controller (IAC) is a new feature in TPTP workbench which allows users to profile a Java application locally and to run a TPTP Test locally without needing the standalone Agent Controller on the local machine.
>   Profiling on a remote machine or running a TPTP test on a remote machine would still need the Agent Controller on that remote machine.
>   The biggest benefit of the Integrated Agent Controller is that it simplifies the usage of TPTP functionality in the local scenario by removing the dependency on the local standalone Agent Controller. There is no need to install and configure the local standalone Agent Controller when using the Profiling and Logging perspective and Test perspective locally.

However, that local agent might not be referenced correctly in one of the TPTP config files, either because:

- it is [already referenced in the workspace](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tptp/msg07230.html) (incorrectly)
  See  `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.tptp.platform.iac.administrator\config\ serviceconfig.xml`
- or because the IAC service is not started automatically:
  Check the connection with the localhost (via Window->preferences->Agent Controller->hosts->Test connection).
  See [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tptp/msg07217.html) (and its follow up) for a working setup.

[This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tptp/msg06879.html) might also be relevant.

---

For those On Linux:

It may be related to `gcc` version or `libstdc++xx-glibcy.y` version, as mentioned in [bug 244213](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=244213) or [bug 240677](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240677)

This [blog post](http://stefaanlippens.net/eclipse_tptp_woes_on_ubuntu_solving_as_nonroot) relates what kind of workaround is possible in his case. May be it could help here.

---

Extract:

> A workaround for this is described in [this blog post](http://www.mesdn.net/blog/index.php?entry=entry081211-114653).
>
> It's pretty straight forward: get a `deb` file <del>[`libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-27_i386.deb`](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-2.95/libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-27_i386.deb)</del> and install it with sudo dpkg ....

(**update Dec. 2010**: gcc before 3.x is no longer available.
You can try with, for instance, [**(`gcc-3.3`) `libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_i386.deb`**](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_i386.deb), replacing all reference to a .deb by this one:

```
sudo dpkg --install libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_i386.deb
```

**Or if you are running on 64 bits**:

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture --install libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_i386.deb
```

Not tested though.)

> The problem is now that the workaround involves root actions.
>   First, one hasn't always the required root permissions to do so.
>   More importantly however, I don't like installing external debs and other stuff as root because it can interfere with the packaging system, pollute system directories and break things in ugly, or worse, unrecoverable ways.
>
> **I always install third party stuff** (with which I mean things that are not available through the standard packaging system) **in my home directory under `~/usr`**.
>   For example, I build autotools-managed software with the option `--prefix=~/usr`, so things end up in `~/usr/bin`, `~/usr/lib`, `~/usr/share`, etcetera.
>
> I managed to install the deb file described above also in `~/usr` as follows.
>   First, I extracted the deb file to a temporary directory to get an idea of its contents:

```
dpkg -x libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-27_i386.deb tmp/
```

> This resulted in the following file tree:

```
tmp/
`-- usr
    |-- lib
    |   |-- libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
    |   `-- libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 -> libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
    `-- share
        `-- doc
            `-- libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2
                |-- README.Bugs.gz
                |-- README.Debian
                |-- changelog.Debian.gz
                `-- copyright
```

> So I just had to move the shared libraries `libstdc++*.so` to `~/usr/lib`, or alternatively, extract the deb file directly int my home directory:

```
dpkg -x libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-27_i386.deb ~/
```

> One important missing piece of the puzzle is to make sure these shared libraries can be found at run time (or compile time in case you want to compile against them).
>   The trick is to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variables, typically in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` startup scripts:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/usr/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_RUN_PATH=$LD_RUN_PATH:~/usr/lib
export LD_RUN_PATH
```

> And Eclipse TPTP profiling lived happily ever after. I hope.

Comment: This solution is for those running on Ubuntu, I'm using Windows 7. Any solution there?

Comment: The link to the deb file is broken, so I'm not sure how relevant all this is.

Answer (score 0):

I found that IAC was disabled by default.
Try Windows/Preferences/Agent Controller/Integrated Agent Controller/Activate the Integrated Agent Controller on demand - enabled